# Make bootstrap navbar become a dropdown on small screen

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, dropdown

I am using a bootstrap navbar and I would like it to become a navbar with navbar-brand on left and dropdown with list items on right when it is displayed on a small screen. Right now I have a pretty good working navbar, but when it is resized to a very small size there is no dropdown on right and list items just disappears at all. And there is a problem with navbar-brand I would like to change its style at the same time the dropdown displayed. I thought about using `@media` but are there an easier solution to this?

This is html:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-transparent" role="navigation">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <span class="navbar-brand">All kinds of pizza</span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="btn">All</li>
                            <li class="btn">Meat taste</li>
                            <li class="btn">Pineapple taste</li>
                            <li class="btn">Mushroom taste</li>
                            <li class="btn">Seafood taste</li>
                            <li class="btn">Vegetarian</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </nav>
```

And this is less:

```
.navbar-nav
{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;

  > li
  {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

.navbar-header
{
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;

  .navbar-brand
  {
    font:@mainFont;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: @shadowToGoOverText;
  }
}
.navbar-brand {float:none;}

.navbar-inner
{
  background:transparent;
}

.navbar-nav
{
  li
  {
    color: white;
    font: @mainFont;
    border: @mainBorder;
    border-color: transparent;
    text-shadow: @shadowToGoOverText;
  }

  li:hover
  {
    color: @mainColor;
    border-color: @borderColor;
    border-radius: @generalRoundness;
    background-color: white;
    text-shadow: none;
  }
```

And its constants:

```
//borders

@mainBorder: 4px dashed #407a15;
@generalRoundness: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
@borderColor: #407a15;

//text
@mainFont: bold 25px Tahoma;
@shadowToGoOverText: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black;
```

If my code seems to be confusing for you feel free to write navbar from scratch and after that I will integrate parts of it into my own.

Comment: First problem is: you forgot to mention what version of Bootstrap you are using. Second would be you are asking for a navbar that would behave exactly like the default Bootstrap navigation, in both [`v3`](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) and [`v4`](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/). When you decide to use a library, you are supposed to use the markup provided by that library.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, ok. I will try default one. Thank you for attention.

Comment: Anytime, Yaroslav. Welcome to SO.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu the default navbar doesn`t do what I need

Comment: It doesn`t convert into dropdown list itself on little screen.

Comment: Ok. Please create either here, using the `<>` button or in `jsFiddle` a snippet with your webpage, as it is output now, so I can see why it doesn't behave like the default navbar. Another option is to provide a link to your live app/website. If I can't inspect, I can't help. Regards,

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu https://github.com/oobarbazanoo/JS-Pizza

Answer (score 0):

I using one navbar and two "ul" elements, one have the display:none, using javascript to detected the display width size, and show only one "ul" element, changing the display property.

```js
    function detectDisplay(){
        var displayWidth = window.screen.width;
        changeMenu(displayWidth);
    }
    
    // show a specific menu according to the display size
    function changeMenu(displayWidt) {
        if (displayWidt < 576) {
            document.getElementById("menu1").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("menu2").style.display = "";
        } else if (displayWidt > 575) {
            document.getElementById("menu1").style.display = "";
            document.getElementById("menu2").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

HTML

```html
 <body onresize="detectDisplay();" onload="detectDisplay();">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div class="container-fluid imgBackground">
                <!-- menu bar -->
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark" style="margin:0 -15px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="UndergroundCR" CssClass="navbar-brand"></asp:Label>
                   <!-- menu 1 -->
                    <ul id="menu1" class="navbar-nav ml-auto" style="display:none;">
                        <li class="nav-item active ">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="index.aspx">Inicio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nuestros Servicios</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Precios</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- menu 2 -->
                    <ul id="menu2" class="navbar-nav ml-auto" style="display:none;">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Note: only tested with Firefox v76